# app engine python is this bug: when open switch interactive console

Tags: python, google-app-engine

While I am working at `localhost:8080`, when I open interactive console and do some operations, like getting list of `Kind` etc  (address: `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/interactive`) then it gives me this error:

`<class 'google.appengine.dist._library.UnacceptableVersionError'>: django 1.2 was requested, but 0.96.4.None is already in use`

This errors happened several times, in similar cases. It is stuck until  restart localhost by `dev_appserver.py`

Is this a bug or what I am doing wrong?

Example for what I did at interactive console:

```
from myapp.models import *
for room in Room.all():
    room.update_time = room.create_time
    room.put()
```

Note:
This is my `django_bootstrap` :

```
import os
import sys
import logging
import __builtin__
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

import pickle
sys.modules['cPicle'] =pickle

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath((os.path.dirname(__file__))))

import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')


import django.core.handlers.wsgi

def main():
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)    

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

my `index.ymal` in root folder says:

```
# AUTOGENERATED

# This index.yaml is automatically updated whenever the dev_appserver
# detects that a new type of query is run.  If you want to manage the
# index.yaml file manually, remove the above marker line (the line
# saying "# AUTOGENERATED").  If you want to manage some indexes
# manually, move them above the marker line.  The index.yaml file is
# automatically uploaded to the admin console when you next deploy
# your application using appcfg.py.
```

Thus each time I open `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore`, this file updated: which is still has the same content but timestamp of file on operating system says it is updated.

I think here, As the `http://localhost:8080` sees that models.py is not the same then it could load it then can not start django_bootstrap.

However if I first open `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore` and then `http://localhost:8080`, it works. So this is why *sometimes* I get error sometimes not: It depends of order urls respective